# how to increase quotas (max number of files) on my shared host, with php.ini setting

Tags: php, file, server, quota

My website is on a server (1&1, linux shared hosting) where total number of files is quota limited at around 260k. That's a major problem. I'm now using text files as main storage, rather than sql database, and I need a lot more (around 500k would be decent).

(These are mostly very small files, a few Ko each, then total space needed is not a related problem).

The hotline tells me I can modify the allowed quota by creating a php.ini with new settings. They don't tell me how to do...

I did not find anything related to that issue on Internet and I'm asking here for help : what is the param to be touched ? I get many answers about file max upload, but nothing about maximum number of files per account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this via php. It sounds like a hosting plan restriction.

Comment: This will better suit as comment not as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I was on holidays last week, with no computer.

I have called the support one more time and it appears it is not doable for shared server user to modify max number of files quota using php.ini. It is not a restriction I can modify by my own.

The original hotline helper I have talked to has given unclear informations.

At the end, Richard is right. Thank you for your contribution.